# Combining two dataframes of dates and values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes loaded from a .csv file. One contains numeric values, the other dates (month-year) for when these numeric values occured. The dates and values are basically mapped to each other. I would like to combine/merge these dataframes to have the dates as the column, and values as the rows. However, as you can see, the dates, though ordered from left to right, they don't all start on the same month.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1, 2, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA],
        [2, 3, 4, pd.NA, pd.NA],
        [4, 5, 6, pd.NA, pd.NA],
        [5, 6, 12, 14, 15]
    ]
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["2021-01", "2021-02", pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA],
        ["2021-02", "2021-03", "2021-04", pd.NA, pd.NA],
        ["2022-03", "2022-04", "2022-05", pd.NA, pd.NA],
        ["2021-04", "2021-05", "2021-06", "2021-07", "2021-08"]
    ]
)
```

**df1**

[image]

**df2**

[image]

Although I managed to create the combined dataframe, the dataframes, df1 and df2 contain ~300k rows, and the approach I thought of is rather slow. **Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same result?**

```py
q = {z: {x: y for x, y in zip(df2.values[z], df1.values[z]) if not pd.isna(y)} for z in range(len(df2))}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(q, orient='index')

idx = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m').argsort()

df.iloc[:, idx]
```

**df3** (result)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
(pd.concat([df1.stack(), df2.stack()], axis=1)
   .reset_index(level=0)
   .pivot(index='level_0', columns=1, values=0)
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Alternative with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
(pd.concat([df1.stack(), df2.stack()], axis=1)
   .droplevel(1).set_index(1, append=True)
   [0].unstack(1)
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

output:

```
  2021-01 2021-02 2021-03 2021-04 2021-05 2021-06 2021-07 2021-08 2022-03 2022-04 2022-05
0       1       2     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1     NaN       2       3       4     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       4       5       6
3     NaN     NaN     NaN       5       6      12      14      15     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with keys parameters, so possible after [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and convert `MutiIndex` to column use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['a','b'])
        .stack()
        .reset_index()
        .pivot('level_0','b','a'))
print (df)
b       2021-01 2021-02 2021-03 2021-04 2021-05 2021-06 2021-07 2021-08  \
level_0                                                                   
0             1       2     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
1           NaN       2       3       4     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
2           NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
3           NaN     NaN     NaN       5       6      12      14      15   

b       2022-03 2022-04 2022-05  
level_0                          
0           NaN     NaN     NaN  
1           NaN     NaN     NaN  
2             4       5       6  
3           NaN     NaN     NaN
```